# Python - Replace null values with empty dicts/array

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, json-normalize

I'd like to replace *null* values with empty array when using pandas json_normalize. here is the sample:

```
{
    "id": {
        "0": "x0123455",
        "1": "x0123456"
    },
    "team": {
        "0": null,
        "1": [
            {
                "name": "Jenny",
                "email": "jenny@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I read somewhere that I need to replace null values with empty dicts to avoid getting errors. How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

As a workaround, I filtered out null values

Comment: Have you tried calling json_normalize on that dict to see what happens with the null values?

Comment: it returns blank value when calling json_normalize. By the way, I'm working on response json and it's returning some null values, but other attributes have `[]` values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may do something simple,
like

```
for item in items:
    for email in item['team'].values():
        if email == null:
            email = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran JSON normalize function on this dictionary (although it was not a JSON object), it provided an output that included the None value.

```
import pandas as pd

test_dict ={
    "id": {"0": "x0123455", "1": "x0123456"},
    "team": {"0": None, "1": [{"name": "Jenny", "email": "jenny@gmail.com"}]},
}

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(test_dict)

print(df)
```

This code produces the following output when I did df.to_csv:

,id.0,id.1,team.0,team.1
0,x0123455,x0123456,,"[{'name': 'Jenny', 'email': 'jenny@gmail.com'}]"

*Note this does not work if the value is null because there is no such thing as null in Python.

I suggest just running with json normalize if it works for you, if not [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255400/exclude-empty-null-values-from-json-serialization) on stack overflow should answer your question with recursive code to remove all null values.